# Can I select an id that starts with "#"

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a homework where I have to style a page without touching the html. Two of the IDs name's start with "#" is there a way I can select them in the css file using the IDs?

Comment: how about using class?

Comment: Hi Shine, it is always good to add the relevant code in your question.

Comment: I'll go out on a limb (I could be wrong) and guess that you might be misunderstanding and that the IDs that are provided to you are just prefaced with that `#` and don't actually "start with a #"

Comment: While you _can_ hack it (as Angel's answer shows), you can also note that by spec, `#` is not a permitted character in an `id` attribute. If possible, making the document compliant would be a good thing.

Comment: @Amadan - depends on what spec you are talking about but an `id` in HTML5 is valid as long as it [contains at least one character](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-id-attribute) - including if that character is an `#`

Comment: @Adam: You're right, I was thinking of XML/XHTML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always use the attribute selector:

```
[id = "#your-id"] {}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways to select it.

- > [the attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)  The CSS attribute selector matches elements based on the presence or value of a given attribute.
  >
  > `[id="#oneId"] {/*style*/}`
- or escaping the character (**you are not supposed to use this special character in fact to name an id**  )

  > https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-escapes#css_identifiers Identifiers in CSS, such as class names in CSS selectors, can begin with - _ a-z or A-Z or a non-ASCII character, but cannot begin with any other ASCII character. However, escaped characters of any type can appear in any location.
  >
  > `#\#anotherId {/* style*/}`

Demo :

```css
[id="#one"] {
  color: red
}

#\#two {
  color: green
}
```

```html
<p id="#one">one , red</p>
<p id="#two">two, green</p>
```

Answer (score -2):

Use [CSS #id selector](https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/sel_id.asp)

Example:

```
//style.css

    #exampleId {
        color: red;
    }
```